# Verilog generate block error

Tags: fpga, verilog, rtl

I have a CORDIC module that I want to instantiate/generate 8 times, basically, I need 8 blocks of CORDIC. So, I have wrote the following statement block, but I get an error:

Error: Syntax error near cordic.

What am I doing wrong?

```
genvar k;
    generate
        for (k = 0; k < 8; k = k + 1)
            begin
                always @(posedge fpga_clk)
                    begin
                        cordic CDC(fpga_clk, rst, phase_word[k], sin_out[k], cos_out[k]);
                    end
            end
    endgenerate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot, and there is no need to put the `cordic` module instantiations inside an `always` block.

```
genvar k;
for (k = 0; k < 8; k = k + 1)
  begin : block
    cordic CDC(fpga_clk, rst, phase_word[k], sin_out[k], cos_out[k]);
  end
```

This create instances `block[0].CDC` through `block[7].CDC` of the `cordic` module. We assume that module already has `always` processes inside it, and they get instanced 8 times as well.

Comment: Thanks. I understood that there is no need of always block or clock edges to make copies of a module. @dave_59